# How to sum all integers between two numbers inclusively using a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, sum

The code must be written using a recursive method, and yes I know this is a horrible approach but I am trying to learn recursion. The method should be able to take two inputs regardless of order and return the sum of all numbers between and including the two inputs. For example, if the input is 2 and 6 or 6 and 2 it should return 20.

```
public static int sumInt(int start, int end) {
        if (start == end) {
            return start + end;
        }
        else if (start < end){
            return start + sumInt(start + 1, end);
        }
        else if (start > end) {
            return end + sumInt (end, start);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This is the solution I have already tried, but it does not include the inputs. When using the example input 2,6 it returns 14, and 6,2 returns 16. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When the two endpoints are equal, you should return `end`, not two times that.
2. When `start > end`, you should also increment `end` in the recursive call since you're adding `end` to the result.

```java
public static int sumInt(int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) {
        return end;
    }
    else if (start < end){
        return start + sumInt(start + 1, end);
    }
    else if (start > end) {
        return end + sumInt (end + 1, start);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This can be simplified using `Math.min` and `Math.max` to reduce casework:

```java
public static int sumInt(int start, int end) {
    if (start == end) return end;
    int first = Math.min(start, end);
    return first + sumInt(first + 1, Math.max(start, end));
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Always forget about the Math methods... probably need to read through all of those sometime.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the code (imho) and still make it recursive, I would employ a helper method.

- `sumInt()` simply calls the helper with the arguments reversed if required.
- `sumIntHelper()` actually computes the recursive sum.

```
System.out.println(sumInt(2, 7));
System.out.println(sumInt(7, 2));
System.out.println(sumInt(12, 12));
    

public static int sumInt(int start, int end) {
    return start > end ? sumIntHelper(end, start)
            : sumIntHelper(start, end);
}

private static int sumIntHelper(int start, int end) {
    if (start+1 < end) {
        return start + sumIntHelper(start + 1, end);
    }
    return start + end;
}
```

prints

```
27
27
24
```